# asterisk - which API to use for creating and managing conferences

Tags: c#, asterisk, asteriskami

I want to create a outbound conferencing application using asterisk in windows - the user can enter a few phone numbers and the system calls all the participants and adds them to the conference. I read a little bit about asterisk APIs, and I saw that I can use the manager API and AGI. I looked at the command reference and I couldn't find any conference related commands. Can this be done using any of these APIs or other APIs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Asterisk you have two potential options for conferencing.

- In 1.8 and older, the preferred application is MeetMe.  MeetMe has a lot of options, but is rather monolithic in its design.  Its also ties you into using DAHDI for timing, and does not support wide band audio formats.
- In 10 and later, the preferred mechanism is ConfBridge.  ConfBridge is more flexible then MeetMe (dynamic DTMF menus, ability to bounce out to the dialplan while still inside a conference, dynamic user/bridge profiles, etc.), supports wide band audio, and has support for video conferencing (without transcoding).

Both have AMI actions that you can use to interface with them, documented [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+10+AMI+Actions).  You can also find more information on ConfBridge in Asterisk [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the command list, I may be wrong but I don't see anything there that creates a conference.

Comment: What do you mean?  Both the MeetMe application and ConfBridge application *create* conferences.  With respect to AGI, you would just directly call the applications.

With AMI, that's not really how it works.  You could Originate calls into a dialplan that calls either your AGI script, or the MeetMe / ConfBridge applications directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exec command of AMI/AGI api.

Using that, you can get any command from asterisk dialplan.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI

Using exec:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+-+documentation+of+application+commands

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsterNET to create Voice applications on .NET (C#)
https://github.com/skrusty/AsterNET